# Laravel 5 QueryException in Connection.php line 673:

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not     match number of tokens (SQL: delete from `preferences` where `tenant_id` = 154 and     `setting_type` = Category and 1 = 1)
```

when I use this function:

```
private function updateSettingsTable($request, $requestType, $settingType)
{
    $redundants = Preference::where('tenant_id', session('tenant'))->where('setting_type', $settingType)->delete();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$this->updateSettingsTable($request, 'categories', 'Category');
```

It seems as if Laravel is removing the quotes around 'Category' before sending it to the query. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private function updateSettingsTable($request, $requestType,$settingType)
{
  $redundants = Preference::where('tenant_id', session('tenant')) ->where('setting_type', "'".$settingType."'")->delete();
 }
```

Comment: interesting - but I don't understand why it's needed here - I have loads of other similar eloquent statements that work fine without adding quotes.